# Printing integers and string values together from json

Tags: json, python-3.5

Maybe I just haven't looked far and close enough in the web, but my question is, is there another way to print both an integer and string together a shorter way.?

the JSON

```
{'id': 19598310, 'accountId': 32292195, 'name': 'mars7327', 'profileIconId': 607, 'revisionDate': 1516584074000, 'summonerLevel': 30}
```

This is my code

```
import requests
import json





summoner = "mars7327";
API_KEY = 'API_KEY';
main = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/"+summoner+"?api_key="+API_KEY;
def summonerinfo():
    get=requests.get(main);
    summoner_detail=get.text;
    summoner_json=json.loads(summoner_detail);
    ide=summoner_json['id'];
    name=summoner_json['name'];
    id2=str(ide);
    name1=str(name);
    print(name1+" "+id2);

summonerinfo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you need to convert the integers to strings in your example is because you are adding them to a string. A better method would be to format a string:

```
print("{} {}".format(name1, id2))
```

The example above does not require converting id2 to a string.

Comment: Is there a way I can print out the integer and the string together without the `ide` and `name`?

Comment: @KanasakiTorisowa `print("{} {}".format(summoner_json['id'], summoner_json['name']))`